# Python - How to convert a string to an integer for RSA encryption

Tags: python, encryption, rsa

I have implemented a simple RSA encryption/decryption program in Python. It works fine when message m is a number.  But if I want to use a message like "hello" how do I convert that to plug it into the m**e which takes an integer? It would still need to be reversed for decryption as well.  I have tried ord() and encode() to create a long integer string of ASCII numbers, but then I can't reverse it.

```py
m = input("Enter message: ")

# Encryption of m
m = int(m)
c = (m**e) % n
print("Encrypted message = %d" % c)
```

Comment: You need a unique encoding and decoding and RSA has a limit for encryption; modulus size. Convert string to bytes than to interger...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use python built-in types, you can use `int.from_bytes` and `int.to_bytes`. [(See docs here.)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#additional-methods-on-integer-types)

```
import math


def string_to_int(s):
    return int.from_bytes(s.encode(), byteorder='little')


def int_to_string(i):
    length = math.ceil(i.bit_length() / 8)
    return i.to_bytes(length, byteorder='little').decode()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = input("Enter message: ")

    m_int = string_to_int(m)
    print(m_int)
    print(int_to_string(m_int))
```

The `string_to_int` function simply converts to bytes using `str.encode`, then converts to an `int` using `int.from_bytes`.

The `int_to_string` function works similarly with `int.to_bytes` and `str.decode`, though it needs to know the length of the `bytes` object to create. To calculate the smallest number of bytes that the integer would fit into, we use divide the number of bits it uses by 8, and round up - if we rounded down then there wouldn't be enough bytes to represent the number.

Comment: That worked!  Thanks so much!